# Clone drive to partition (onto 2nd drive with existing partitions), make both partitions on 2nd drive bootable

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, clone

1. I have a failing hard drive (1tb) with a bootable Windows 7 installation on it.
2. I have a new hard drive (3tb) with a new bootable Windows 7 installation (on one 1tb partition).

How can I clone the first hard drive to a 2nd partition on drive 2, and make both partitions on drive 2 bootable?

.

---

*Extra notes:*

*- Since hdd1 is failing, would a certain cloning software work better than another (clonezilla, ddrescue, wd acronis, etc)?*

*- Since a clone of a failing hard drive won't result in a perfect copy, what's the best step to perform after a clone? Can I perform a 2nd (more thorough) clone and only replace newly recovered data?*

*- Hdd 1 is using nearly all 1tb of its space (MBR format).

(Contains: win7 with tons of programs and customized settings that took months to configure, which is why a bootable clone would be nice.)*

*- Hdd 2 is using only 50gb of its 1tb partition (3tb drive. MBR format).

(Contains: an install of win7 SP1  that I'm currently using, with some programs, customized settings, and new files, and will use as my new primary OS to save time if the clone doesn't work properly.)*

Comment: You don't have a large enough disk since you are limited to only 2TB of that 3TB disk and its not a full 2TB.  The math does not compute.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm cloning a 1tb disk to a 3tb disk... The current OS on disk 2 is in a 1tb partition, and there's an additional empty 2tb partition to use to copy the 1tb from disk 1. (Maybe I should have also said everything I'm running is 64-bit).

Comment: @Ramhound The 2tb limit you're referring to is only a limit to the size of a single partition and only when using MBR. You can make multiple 2tb (or smaller) partitions on one disk to use all the space of hard drives larger than 2tb (as I have). You can also use GPT instead of MBR to make one large 3tb partition (which works natively in windows vista and up), but to also make that 3tb partition a bootable main OS partition with Windows (and not just a secondary data drive), you have to have a motherboard that boots with UEFI instead of BIOS, and a 64-bit version of windows more recent than XP.

Comment: I know all that and if his hardware supported GPT he likely would be using it